# Page reload (Webview.loadUrl) results in Javascript not being (fully) processed

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

The following trick for getting page's HTML content after javascript has been rendered works pretty well, when placed in the `onNewPicture()` of a `WebView`'s `PictureListener`:

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
```

However, for some reason it works only the first time the page is loaded. That is, the application's first such `WebView.loadUrl()` call gets a completely rendered version of the page.

Thereafter, if I reload/refresh the page (same exact URL), the output of `HTMLOUT.showHTML()` appears to be the original HTML+javascript *before* the page was rendered.

The strange thing is that *visually*, on the `WebView` itself, all content is there! (albeit after a significant delay... I can see the WebView's hourglass spinning, perhaps it takes too long for Javascript to be re-processed?)

This seems to suggest either an initialization problem (in my code), a bug in WebView, or some caching principle that is well known to experienced web programmers but with which I am not familiar with yet.

But then it gets even more interesting: Subsequent calls to `WebView.loadUrl()` result in the aforementioned failure multiple (3-10) times until... the page is miraculously **fully rendered** again! (and then multiple failures again, and so on)

Which may suggest timing problem?

Any suggestion on how to debug or troubleshoot this?

Comment: what version of android are you developing on and what device? there are at least ten similar questions here with no answers, this is a real bug in Android and kind of pitiful that is is even a bug! lets get to the bottom of this, Bug reports can be submitted here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inject the javascript after the page loads!   Took me forever to figure it out